# How to add meta data to header with Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using media queries for my site which works fine for mobile devices served from my development server.

When I upload to firebase hosting, mobile view stops working on mobile devices, I have found this is because some meta information is not taken across when uploaded.

Firebase does not support meta tag changes using firebase.json config. This seems odd, how else are you mean to create efficient media queries?

I would like to add this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the domain forwarding from DNS was set to masking, this created an Iframe which ignored the meta data that i had added in the index file, correct hosting setup corrected this and resolved issue.